# Sci-fi book with the title 'out' or 'world' or related synonyms

Tags: story-identification, books

I read it back in 2001. It was the first book in a series. The protagonist could enter 'virtual worlds'. I remember in one 'experience' she lived how it would feel to die (the mental thoughts that went through the person's mind). I also remember a scene where I believe she was doing an African ritual dance the night before a 'battle'.

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You've put "virtual worlds" and "experience" and "battle" into quotes. Are these specific words that were used in the novel?

Comment: No, just to highlight that it could be something similar, I was going for air quotes.

Comment: How are out and world synonyms? Do you mean like 'off-world' or 'off-planet', that sort of thing?

Answer (score 4):

*[City of Golden Shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Golden_Shadow)* by Tad Williams seems to be the book you refer to. The book was published in 1996 (read online [here](https://archive.org/details/cityofgoldenshad00will/mode/2up)) and was indeed the first of a series.

The protagonist is Renie Sulaweyo which matches your description of the protagonist being female. The story itself is about a virtual reality network called the "Other land" and the protagonist does indeed take part in an African dance.

> The fire was surprisingly small, but she could feel its warmth.
> However, Xabbu did not give her much chance to enjoy it. He took two
> strings of what appeared to be dried cocoons from his pouch and tied
> one around each of his ankles. When he shook them, they made a soft
> buzzing rattle.
>
> "Come." He rose and beckoned. "Now we will dance."
>
> "Dance?"
>
> "Do you see the moon?" He pointed. It floated in the blackness like a
> pearl in a pool of oil. "And the ring around it? Those are the marks
> that the spirits make when they dance around it, for they feel it to
> be a fire, a fire just like this." He reached out and took her hand.
> Although a part of her could not forget that they were in separate
> tanks, yards apart, she also felt his familiar presence. However
> physics might define it, he was definitely holding her hand, leading
> her into a strange hopping dance.
>
> "I don't know anything about. . . ."
>
> "It is a healing dance. It is important. We have a journey ahead of
> us, and we have suffered much pain already. Just do as I do."

Though the title does not include the words "out" or "world" you could have confused these two words for "Other" and "Land" quite easily after 23 years.

Comment: This answer would be better if you removed all the Bing malarkey and just wrote a proper one :-)

Comment: fair. Doing that right now

Comment: I've taken the liberty of swapping in a book quote. Dancing plays a fairly important part in the novel. It's mentioned about a dozen times, but this *seems* to be the passage that OP is referring to.

Comment: Thanks, Valorum, I had found that quote but wasn't quite sure if it was really the "African ritual dance" that OP referred to, so I chose to keep it as it was.

Comment: You can always edit it back out if you think I've overstepped. It's your answer :-)

Comment: I'll leave it as it is. It's a good effort from you too and I've decided on keeping it :0